# android - if service onDestory() is not guaranteed to be called, where should I release/remove listeners etc?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver, ondestroy

So, I have a service which its `onDestory()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopLocationUpdates();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    Foreground.get(this).removeListener(this);
    // Here I have some code which sets shared preferences values
    phoneDataManager.markLastLocation();
    toastHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I have a lot going on in here (disconnecting and stopping location updates, do some changes in SQLite database, and set some `SharedPreferences` values.

From what I read, `onDestory` is not guaranteed to be called. one scenario what I saw that it doesn't get called is -

Running the service -> closing application (removing from app list) -> I bring service to the foreground using `service.startForeground(1, notification);` , Notification is showing -> clicking notification action which fires a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class ServiceShutDownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
        context.stopService(serviceIntent);
    }

}
```

The `context.stopService(serviceIntent);` **should** call `onDestory` but it doesn't get called -> so all the code in `onDestory` wasn't executed.

What is the best practice for this problem? Ideally I want to have a piece of code that is **guaranteed** to be called when service is stopped.

Comment: "I want to have a piece of code that is guaranteed to be called when service is stopped" -- that does not exist. What is guaranteed is that either `onDestroy()` will be called, your process will have been terminated (in which case all your listeners and stuff are already gone), or you crashed with an unhandled exception.

Comment: got it. so about the shared preferences and DB stuff, I think it sould be best to have another class which its job will be to do all of this stuff, and call it from the broadcastReceiver. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should not be concerned about situations where `onDestroy()` is not called because this means that the System is forcefully and immediately destroying the service (and all of its associated resources and local variables, kept in memory).

It is recommended to always put here the code that releases persistent handlers like MediaPlayer, BroadcastReceiver, GPS location updates, etc. This is good practice and will handle 90% of the situations where the service is gracefully stopped.

However, if you want to implement some custom "last minute checks", you are right that this method may never be called by the system and this code will never get executed. Your development strategy should follow this pattern and should not depend on this since there is no other reliable way of knowing when a Service is about to be destroyed.

As a last resort, you can listen for the [Application::onLowMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory()) callback, which is triggered when the System is low on memory and is close to starting killing processes, but even this is not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: I see.  What I think I'll do is have the removing of the location updates/habdler in `onDestroy()` because when the process gets killed,  they will bo gone anyway. About the last minute shared preferences and DB stuff,  I'll have another class doing that.  Does that sound OK?